# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, sax

this is my xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<settings></settings>
```

and my method is shown below

```
public  void load( String fileName ) {
...
Document xmlDocument = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = null;
try
{
  builder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  xmlDocument = builder.parse(new File (fileName));
}
catch( Exception e )
{
  Log.write(e);
}
...
}
```

When I invoke my method I receive the following:

```
[task] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
[task] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
[task] at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
[task] at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
[task] at MyClass.load(MyClass.java:49)
```

I am completely confused.

Thanks for any ideas.

-Cyril

Comment: Check `File.exists()` before `builder.parse()`, just to make sure it is where you think it is.

Comment: I tried to run this code and it was working for me.

Comment: I has been thinking that this is an encoding issue (declared utf-8 xml file encoded as non utf-8), but my test didn't prove it.

Answer (score 2):

problem may exist in struts.xml file.  The following line must be included in struts.xml file.

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
```

and `<package>` tag must be written inside `<struts>` tag inside sturts.xml file.

Comment: problem may exist with any xml file if the document is not well formated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the content type `content-type:text/xml; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Nope, unfortunately there is nothing wrong about the content type